# how to give the click event for bimap in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i have created the manager with rounded rectangles. i have added small bitmap to that manager in the left corner. i want to change the bitmap if i click on that bitmap. 
how to give the invoke action to the bitmap
i have tried with invoke action method. but it is not  working. please tell me if anyone knows
 i have used

```
 roundedManager = new RoundedManager();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/delete_icon.png");
    BitmapField bitField = new BitmapField(bitmap, ACTION_INVOKE ) {
    protected boolean invokeaction(int action){
      dialog.alert("clicked");
     return true;
```

but it is not working

Comment: In the advanced UI library, you have a nice BitmapButtonField that might be helpful. Check it: http://docs.blackberry.com/es-es/developers/deliverables/29251/About_the_advanced_UI_library_1626501_11.jsp

Comment: i have tried with that. but i am not able to click that bitmap by using that field